# How to get GitLab project name/URL by using Project id in GitLab API

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

Is there a way to search for GitLab projects by Project ID?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to get single project by requesting `/projects/:id` endpoint: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#get-single-project

For example:

```
curl https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/278964
```

The response is going to contain `name`, `ssh_url_to_repo`,  `http_url_to_repo`, `web_url`, etc:

```json
{
  "id": 3,
  "description": null,
  "default_branch": "master",
  "visibility": "private",
  "ssh_url_to_repo": "git@example.com:diaspora/diaspora-project-site.git",
  "http_url_to_repo": "http://example.com/diaspora/diaspora-project-site.git",
  "web_url": "http://example.com/diaspora/diaspora-project-site",
  "readme_url": "http://example.com/diaspora/diaspora-project-site/blob/master/README.md",
  "tag_list": [ //deprecated, use `topics` instead
    "example",
    "disapora project"
  ],
  "topics": [
    "example",
    "disapora project"
  ],
  "owner": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Diaspora",
    "created_at": "2013-09-30T13:46:02Z"
  },
  "name": "Diaspora Project Site",
  "name_with_namespace": "Diaspora / Diaspora Project Site",
  "path": "diaspora-project-site",
  "path_with_namespace": "diaspora/diaspora-project-site",
  "issues_enabled": true,
...
```